# Searching open and close business hours with thinking sphinx in rails 3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, indexing, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have an interesting problem that maybe someone can figure out.  I have a business model that I want to search through, so I hook in thinking_sphinx into it and now I can search.

Now my business model has_many hours.

```
class Business
has_many :hours
define_index ...

class Hour
belongs_to :business
```

My hours table contains the following columns: business_id, day_of_week(int), open_time(mysql time), close_time(mysql_time).  One other issue to compound the problem is that there could be multiple open/close times for each day.  For example: open Monday 8:00-12:15 and 15:00-20:00

If I want to add a filter on my website to only display open businesses in the search, is there a way I can index my hours into the sphinx index and search via :with?

Anyone got any ideas how to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably isn't ideal, but you should be able to get a search working - however, it'll be via the Hour model, rather than Business.

```
define_index do
  indexes business.name, :as => :business

  has business_id
  has day_of_week
  has 'CAST(open_hour AS INT)',  :as => :open_hour,  :type => :integer
  has 'CAST(close_hour AS INT)', :as => :close_hour, :type => :integer
end
```

I'm not certain about the casting of the times - but essentially we just want to be dealing with integers, Sphinx has no time data type.

Searching will probably look something like this:

```
now  = Time.zone.now
time = (now - now.beginning_of_day).to_i
Hour.search 'foo',
  :with => {
    :day_of_week => now.wday,
    :open_hour   => 0..time,
    :close_hour  => time..240000
  },
  :group_by       => 'business_id',
  :group_function => :attr
```

This will get you hour objects grouped by business id that are open - so you won't get duplicate businesses.

All theory, but give it a spin, let me know how you go :)

Comment: Doing this against the BusinessHour model, how could I handle the case where business hours isn't the only thing they are filtering for.  e.g. they are searching by business name, category and also hours?

Comment: You'd need to have fields or attributes drawing those pieces of data in via associations, like is done above for for the business name. Then you can use :with (for attributes) or :conditions (for fields) to filter accordingly.

Comment: I had originally returned a lot more business results than needed and then checked if they were open/closed in memory.  It was really poorly written and slow.  I finally got around to implementing your method and it works well.  Not all businesses have hours, so I have 2 different indexes.  I use the normal business_index for normal queries and use the hours_index for when the open/closed filter is selected.  Thanks Pat.

Comment: One other hurdle was that in my search results I was ordering by distance, and the :group_by and :group_function were breaking the :order scope in my search.  I just ended up dropping the :group scopes because the business hours will never overlap within a business, therefore I don't have to worry about the same business being returned twice.

Answer (score 0):

First off you'll need to change your Hours model to "belongs_to" instead of has_one, so that the Hours model will know it directly links to the business that is attached to.  You'll probably also want to have the open_time, close_time, and day_of_week columns indexed together, so that you can quickly search them together.

```
add_index :hours, [:day_of_week, :open_time, :close_time]
```

In order to find the open businesses, you could make a scope that would look like the following.  I'm assuming you're using ActiveRecord.

```
class Hour < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :business

  scope :open, lambda { |day, time| { :conditions => ["hours.day_of_week = ? AND hours.open_time >= ? AND hours.close_time < ?", day, time, time] } }
end
```

This way to find the open businesses you would just have to do:

```
Hour.open.includes(:business)
```

And each of the businesses that are open will be there attached to their Hours model.  If you wanted to iterate over them and access the business's info, you could do:

```
Hour.open.includes(:business).each do |hour|
  puts "#{hour.business.name} is open! It closes at #{hour.close_time}."
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I edited my question to correctly display belongs_to.  Anyway, I'm not really trying to figure out if a business is open, rather integrate sphinx search with displaying only open businesses.  Maybe I don't understand your answer, but you defined an index, but didn't show me how to use it.

Comment: I don't know Sphinx, but I assume based-on [the docs](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/1.10/sphinxql-select.html) that the generated filter above would work for sphinx.  I don't know if it directly maps though with the Ruby api.